# SpringCloud Gateway high CPU utilization of 99%

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, lettuce

We have 4 gateway services in different servers. The CPU utilization of one server suddenly increased to 99% serveral days ago. And it has bean holding like this from then.We used command `top -p -H pid` to see which thread of the process occupied the most usage of CPU:
[CPU usage of thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSUcZ.png)

And I convert the thread ID to hex, and find the thread stack of the correlated thread:
[thread stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inh3L.png)

SpringBoot version: 2.6.8

SpringCloud version: 2021.0.1

JDK version: 1.8

Have someone ever met the same problem? How to solve this? What reasons probably be of this problem?